# Interactivity on a remote loaded HTML into JQUERY UI Dialog

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

### **Background**

I have been using the JQuery UI plugin for creating a dialog that loads dynamic content.

So I load up an html document that displays a series of selectable items with checkboxes containing values: A, B, C, D, E

So let's say I checked off "A, C, E"

I press a submit button, which makes use of an AJAX call to the server. The server takes in the data "A, C, E", performs a series of queries and spits out data and html to hold the data contents. Like:

```
<input id="radio1" name="selGroup" type="radio" value="1"><p class="test"> 1 </p>
<input id="radio3" name="selGroup" type="radio" value="3"><p class="test"> 3 </p>
<input id="radio5" name="selGroup" type="radio" value="5"><p class="test"> 5 </p>
<input id="enterBttn" type="button" value="Submit">
```

This html content comes back to the client and get's dumped into:

```
<div id="dialogCheck" title="Select one of these options"></div>
```

This is done by using the jQuery:

```
$("#dialogCheck").html(content);
```

### **Test**

So I check to see if everything is working, and it does. I get a dialog box with my radio buttons and values that I want to select. But now I want to add some interactivity.

### **Problem**

When I open up a dialog box with the injected html from the server, it shows the contents on the screen, but when I want to see the new html on the original source code. It doesn't exist. It just shows up as:

```
 <div id="dialogCheck" title="Select one of these options"></div>
```

When I used JQuery's "$("#dialogCheck").html(content);" to insert. I read the documentation, and it mentions how it doesn't append html to the original source code. So My question is, how am I supposed to add JQuery scripts on top of the html that I inject?

### **The Wierd**

If I pass in something that looks like this:

```
$("#enterBttn").click(function(){ 
     $( "#dialogCheck" ).dialog("destroy");
 });
```

It works! The enterBttn I created destroys the dialog box. **However** if I want to add hover functionality, like if I want to highlight text or outline divs on top of the dialog box, it won't work because it doesn't exist on the original source code.

```
$(".test").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).append($("<span> ***</span>"));
    },
    function(){
        $(this).find("span:last").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One CAN use event handling on html elements inserted through AJAX. 
The jquery ON() http://api.jquery.com/on/ function can be used for that purpose, or when an older version of jquery is used, use the LIVE() function.

Comment: Hi, your answer gave me a clue and helped me figure out what's wrong. I'm posting my solution below. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference if new HTML is in "the original source code" or not (except that debugging is easier and page can be easily saved by user on the client side). But if you really want something to be in "the original source code", then you should not use AJAX and instead of it you should reload the whole page and insert your additional HTML on the server side.

So, everything should work regardless of the HTML source. I guess your code doesn't work because you execute it in the wrong time (for example, before inserting new HTML). Could you please add more details?

Comment: Hi, gave you a one up because I completely forgot that the original source code only gets changed when you reload the page

Answer (score 0):

Okay, figured out what happened:

Both of these worked:

```
$("#enterBttn").hover(function(){
    $(".attriblst").append($("<span> ***</span>"));;
}, function(){
    $(".attriblst").find("span:last").remove();
});
```

and:

```
$("#dialogCheck").on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        $("p").append($("<span> ***</span>"));
    },
    mouseleave: function(){
        $("p").find("span:last").remove();
    }
 },"#enterBttn");
```

What happened was the scope of where I inserted my code. I was keeping them on the document ready portion, if I took it out and placed it in the function I used to call my dialogue box (outside of the document ready), then it worked! Thanks guys :)